# What is a rank-1 constraint system?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, circuit

Why not rank-2 constraint system or rank-3 constraint system?

How do rank-1 constraint systems link to circuits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "rank-1" specifically refers to the rank of the matrix which is produced.

As for the link to circuits, in zk-SNARKS at least, an arithmetic circuit is converted into a R1CS. Each constraint corresponds to one logic gate.

Here's a more detailed walkthrough by Vitalik Buterin: https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/quadratic-arithmetic-programs-from-zero-to-hero-f6d558cea649

Comment: and maybe this is a duplicate: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55963/converting-to-rank-one-constraint-system?rq=1

Comment: Why does it need to be rank-1?

Comment: I did some more research and it seems, according to this paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/507.pdf that the rank-1 is referring to each of the quadratic equations in A*B+C = 0 . Hope that helps!

Comment: so what's a R2CS?