# Generic name for R1CS vs. AIR

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks, starks

In the zero-knowledge cryptography nomenclature, we have multiple *representations* of arbitrary computation suitable for submission to various *proof backends* (e.g. [Groth16](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf)). Two specific examples spring to mind: [rank-1 constraint systems (R1CS)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67857/what-is-a-rank-1-constraint-system) and Algebraic Intermediate Representations (AIR).

**What are these called?**

Comment: Best I can seem to come up with is "relation" or "representation" which are accurate but seemingly broad. Source: https://github.com/arkworks-rs/.github/blob/main/profile/README.md

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, R1CS, PLONK and AIR are 3 different *arithmetic circuit / constraints systems* ("backends").

All of these characterize NP and work using arithmetic over finite prime fields.

Other languages that characterize NP are for example 3-SAT. So it should be possible to define ZK with a 3-SAT backend:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/135457/is-there-a-zero-knowledge-proof-for-sat

> An interesting side question would be: why are arithmetic circuits seemingly preferred to SAT based ones? One possible answer: using arithmetic circuits allows to use advanced math available, eg compressing polynomials

Also compare to the verifier-based definition of NP:

"Given any instance I of problem Π \Pi and witness W, if there exists a verifier V so that given the ordered pair (I, W) as input, V returns "yes" in polynomial time if the witness proves that the answer is "yes" or "no" in polynomial time otherwise, then Π \Pi is in NP." (wikipedia)